# Banners on iOS when App is in the Foreground

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

My question is twofold.
1) I am wondering whether I can use **banners** (aka toast messages) on iOS 11 when my **app is in the foreground** or whether my App will be rejected because of it. When I am talking about a banner I am referring to a message like in the following screenshot 
[image]

The Human Interface Guidelines are not clear on whether I can use a banner while my App is in the forground 
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/notifications/
2) Xamarin Forms does not provide banner notifications so which third-party software would work well for local notifications?

Answer (score 3):

For Displaying banner while app is in running mode you have to use customization. Please add below class file in your iOS App.

```
using UserNotifications;
public class UserNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    {
        #region Constructors
        public UserNotificationCenterDelegate()
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region Override Methods

        public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
        {
            // Do something with the notification
            Console.WriteLine("Active Notification: {0}", notification);

            // Tell system to display the notification anyway or use
            // `None` to say we have handled the display locally.
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);           
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

This will display banner in you app while app is in foreground.

Comment: in FinishedLaunching call this class   
   // Watch for notifications while the app is active
 UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate ();
   
   For more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=vsmac

Answer (score 0):

Many app have alert ,you go it,my company also has alert ,it can pass app review

Comment: Many app not abb

Comment: Would you have an example (name of the App)?